# RStan vectorizing a loop

Tags: vectorization, stan

I am trying to learn STAN.  I understand that vectorizing loops in STAN (as in R) improves efficiency.  But I have not figured out how to do this correctly.  The STAN model below is from Sorenson et al.

```
  data {
  int<lower=1> N;                //number of data points
  real rt[N];                    //reading time
  real<lower=-1,upper=1> so[N];  //predictor
}

parameters {
  vector[2] beta;            //intercept and slope
  real<lower=0> sigma_e;     //error sd
}

model {
  real mu;
  for (i in 1:N){                   // likelihood
    mu = beta[1] + beta[2]*so[i];
    rt[i] ~ lognormal(mu,sigma_e);
  }
}
```

I tried the following edits to the model block:

```
model {
  vector[N] mu;
    mu = beta[1] + beta[2]*so;
    rt ~ lognormal(mu,sigma_e);
}
```

But I am told that this block is malformed, with an error following "so" in line 3.  I think that this line would work in R, but evidently not in STAN.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for help.

I seem to have figured it out.  I had to edit the data block to enter "so" as a vector rather than simply as a real[N].  What's the difference between "real[N]" and "vector[N]"?

```
data {
  int<lower=1> N;                //number of data points
  real rt[N];                    //reading time
  vector<lower=-1,upper=1>[N] so;  //predictor
}
```

Comment: The manual has a chapter on vectors vs. arrays---the difference is memory layout and access and availability of matrix operators and linear algebra.  The efficiency gain is only if you are dealing with matrixes (more efficient memory usage than doing it in a loop) or functions of parameters (cuts down on interpreted evaluations with virtual functions during derivative propagation).  You can just replace `mu` with its definition the lognormal, or you can use compound declare-define and put the definition and declaration in one line.  P.S.  It's "Stan" because it's not an acronym.

Comment: Thanks, Bob.  I'll read the chapter.

Comment: I see.  Stan grammar is like C++, not like R.  Arrays can't use matrix algebra.  While one can extract a single row from a matrix, there is no parallel simple way to extract a column.  This all makes sense when one thinks about it.  But it is a bit of a problem for someone that comes to Stan from (and through) R.  Is there any plan for incorporating something like vector X <- matrix[,x]?

Comment: It's more like than C++.  In R, you have `x %*% y` for matrix product, whereas in Stan you have `x * y`.  Stan does this so it doesn't have to guess if you have a row or column matrix and so that it can infer the type of the result.  Stan supports slicing, e.g., `matrix[3, 4] a; ...; vector[3] b = a[ , 2];  row_vector[4] c = a[1];`

Comment: Got it.  Matrix slicing should do fine to get a column vector.  Thanks!